# Android Standard ListView Item doesn't enlarge on long text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

i have a problem using the standard android listview. if the text is to long to be displayed in one listview item i would like, that this item enlarges itself.

here is a screenshot of how it looks like now:
http://www.abload.de/image.php?img=unbenanntdjupi.png

i'm using also another listview with a custom layout, there it's no problem: the listview-item enlarges itself.

fyi: im using actionbarsherlock so i extend my activity from 'SherlockListActivity'.

i hope one of you can help me... because of implementing a custom listview in this case is a huge overhead :/

thanks in advance!

// edit: it's the standard "simple_list_item_single_choice"... actually i don't want to customize it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
    />
```

here's the code how i added it to my layout:

```
    <ListView 
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

// edit after implementing iturki's answer:
it solves the problem for android 4.x but not on devices with android level 10.

Exception:

```
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.CheckedTextView
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:332)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1598)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  ... 42 more
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x2
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:463)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1957)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:344)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.widget.CheckedTextView.<init>(CheckedTextView.java:58)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at android.widget.CheckedTextView.<init>(CheckedTextView.java:54)
08-30 14:25:04.049: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  ... 45 more
```

i think these are the most important points:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.CheckedTextView
...
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x2
```

Comment: Post the xml code of the list's row

Comment: <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="211dp" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
```

to:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

This will make your list's rows expand to fit their content.

Comment: your answers works well for android 4.x, but not level 10. i paste the exception on level 10 in my first post.